# Raspberry Pi relays and Python, how do I turn off and on a relay in separate functions?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I'm new to Raspberry Pi and are working on a Pi3 program that will switch on and off an irrigation pump though a 1 channel relay.

I've made a function that works well, that takes a delay variable and starts the relay then waits for the delay until it stops the relay again.

However, I also need to be able to turn the relay on in another function, and leave it on until the user turns it off again, and I can't seem to get that working.

When I try it, nothing happens with the relay (except for the normal having power indicating led on it).

This is my working function:

```
#This function switches on the relay for a set period of time, and then shuts it off again
def relay_control(wait_time):

    # Sleeping for a second
    time.sleep(1)

    print("Relay control function")

    # We will be using the BCM GPIO numbering
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    # Selecting which GPIO to target
    GPIO_CONTROL = 6

    # Set CONTROL to OUTPUT mode
    GPIO.setup(GPIO_CONTROL, GPIO.OUT)

    # Starting the relay
    GPIO.output(GPIO_CONTROL, True)

    # Sleeping for set amount of time
    try:
        time.sleep(wait_time)
    except:
        time.sleep(60)
        print("Setting delay failed, using default 60 seconds")

    # Stopping the relay
    GPIO.output(GPIO_CONTROL, False)

    # Cleanup
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

And then I have tried these two functions, but it just doesn't work:

```
#This function switches on the relay - Doesn't currently work
def relay_on():

    # Sleeping for a second
    time.sleep(1)

    # We will be using the BCM GPIO numbering
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    # Selecting which GPIO to target
    GPIO_CONTROL = 6

    # Set CONTROL to OUTPUT mode
    GPIO.setup(GPIO_CONTROL, GPIO.OUT)

    #Starting the relay
    GPIO.output(GPIO_CONTROL, False)

    #Logging the event
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filename='/home/pi/GardenBrain/events.log', level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info('Relay has been manually switched on, from functions.py')

    time.sleep(5)

    #Cleanup
    GPIO.cleanup()

#This function switches on the relay off - Doesn't currently work
def relay_off():

    # Sleeping for a second
    time.sleep(1)

    # We will be using the BCM GPIO numbering
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    # Selecting which GPIO to target
    GPIO_CONTROL = 6

    # Set CONTROL to OUTPUT mode
    GPIO.setup(GPIO_CONTROL, GPIO.OUT)

    #Stopping the relay
    GPIO.output(GPIO_CONTROL, True)

    #Logging the event
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filename='/home/pi/GardenBrain/events.log', level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info('Relay has been manually switched off, from functions.py')

    #Cleanup
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Can anyone see what the problem is and help me get it working?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Also, the working function seem to freeze my Raspberry Pi for a while. It's all powered though the GPIO pins, and the system has a 7" touchscreen display (which the system is being USB powered through), the mentioned 230v 1-channel relay and a Sense Hat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by writing the function in a different way. This one works well and both starts and stops the relay as intended.

```
#This function switches on the relay on or off and expects the argument 'on' or 'off'
def relay_manual(action):

    # Selecting which GPIO to target
    GPIO_CONTROL = 6

    if action == "on":

        # Sleeping for a second
        time.sleep(1)

        # We will be using the BCM GPIO numbering
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

        # Set CONTROL to OUTPUT mode
        GPIO.setup(GPIO_CONTROL, GPIO.OUT)

        #Starting the relay
        GPIO.output(GPIO_CONTROL, True)

        #Logging the event
        logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filename='/home/pi/GardenBrain/events.log', level=logging.INFO)
        logging.info('Relay has been manually switched on, from functions.py')

    elif action == "off":

        try:
            #Stopping the relay
            GPIO.output(GPIO_CONTROL, False)

        except:
            # We will be using the BCM GPIO numbering
            GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

            # Set CONTROL to OUTPUT mode
            GPIO.setup(GPIO_CONTROL, GPIO.OUT)

            #Starting the relay
            GPIO.output(GPIO_CONTROL, False)

        #Logging the event
        logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filename='/home/pi/GardenBrain/events.log', level=logging.INFO)
        logging.info('Relay has been manually switched off, from functions.py')

        #Cleanup
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the code `GPIO.setmode()` and `GPIO.setup()` out of your functions as it only need to be setup once.

This is how the code some looks like:

```
def relay_on():
    GPIO.output(GPIO_CONTROL, False)

    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filename='/home/pi/GardenBrain/events.log', level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info('Relay has been manually switched on, from functions.py')

def relay_off():
    GPIO.output(GPIO_CONTROL, True)

    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filename='/home/pi/GardenBrain/events.log', level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info('Relay has been manually switched off, from functions.py')


# The main program setup the GPIO
GPIO_CONTROL = 6
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_CONTROL, GPIO.OUT)

# Get input from user to turn on or off relay
while True:
    data = input("Input 'on'/'off' to turn on/off relay, or 'exit' to end ")
    if data == 'on':
        relay_on()
    elif data == 'off':
        relay_off()
    elif data == 'exit':
        # program end, clean up GPIO
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Should I move those out of the function, even if the function is imported from another python file? So that file 1 has the GPIO main setup part and also runs the relay functions that are imported from file 2?

Comment: yes, you need to define the relay_on and relay_off functions to only include the logic for controlling the relay GPIO pin, not the setup code.

Comment: `from file2 import relay_on, relay_off` is the same as including the functions on your main file1 directly. Please accept the answer if this is worked and help you.

Comment: I just need to be able to understand this so that I can test it properly. When do I use the GPIO.cleanup()? After each run of the functions? Or do I do that after days of switching on and off the relay? And what does that do?

Comment: 'GPIO.cleanup()` is to reset all the GPIO pins when you exiting or ending the program. See the [documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/)

Comment: Thanks for the help @hcheung but this still doesn't work. I get `NameError: global name 'GPIO_CONTROL' is not defined` error when I try your solution. So I replaced the `GPIO.output(GPIO_CONTROL, True)`with `GPIO.output(bcmnumber, True)` , changed function to take an argument in as such `relay_off(bcmnumber)` and input GPIO.CONTROL when running the function like so `relay_off(GPIO_CONTROL)` and that seems to run in the terminal, but it doesn't turn the relay on and off as it should. Same problem I had before.. :(

Comment: It seems no longer related to the programming. What relay shield you are using and how do you connect the relay to the GPIO.

Comment: I solved it myself by writing the function differently. Posted the answer to this question :) Thanks for your help @hcheung